# Android: Intercept AJAX call from WebView

Tags: android, ajax, webview

I want a `HTML/javascript` application, running in a `WebView` to make `AJAX` calls that are handled by the `Java` code.
Ideal would be to just intercept the call (easy, just use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`) and 'return' some data.
However, I don't find a way to 'return' a response to the `WebView`, other than calling a `javascript` function using `loadUrl()`.
This will not work for me, as the `HTML/javascript` app is a drop-in application which I don't control. As far as the HTML/javascript app concerns, it just does an `AJAX` call and receives some data back.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: can get ajax response after send form data? form webpage display in webview from remote url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the method described in the question anyway;

I intercepted some specific requests like: `foo://bar/get/1?callback=foobar` then parsed the `URL` and called a javascript callback function with the actual data.
The callback function was defined in the query-part of the `URL`, so in the above example that would be: `foobar();`

Calling that function was easy, just use: `yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:foobar('somedata')");`

Comment: Erik can u please elaborate, how u have overloadedURL for the AJAX request handling and also tell me how to handle the AJAX request from Java.. also i dun know the call intercept mechanism... i m trapped in same problem ... Help needed.. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

Good news everyone: With API level 11, they put in the `shouldInterceptRequest` method into the `WebViewClient` class. It also fires on requests the application inside the `WebView` triggers. You can override it as follows:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)
{
    if (magicallyMatch(url))
        return new WebResourceResponse("application/json", "utf-8", magicallyGetSomeInputStream());

    return null;
}
```

From the [Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29):

> public WebResourceResponse **shouldInterceptRequest** (WebView view, String url)
>
> Since: API Level 11
>
> Notify the host
>   application of a resource request and
>   allow the application to return the
>   data. If the return value is null, the
>   `WebView` will continue to load the
>   resource as usual. Otherwise, the
>   return response and data will be used.
>   NOTE: This method is called by the
>   network thread so clients should
>   exercise caution when accessing
>   private data.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `view` The `WebView` that is requesting the resource.
>
> `url` The raw url of the resource.
>
> **Returns**
>
> A `WebResourceResponse` containing the
>   response information or null if the
>   `WebView` should load the resource
>   itself.

Also check [WebResourceResponse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceResponse.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: can get ajax response after send form data? form webpage display in webview from remote url

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) to intercept the AJAX calls along with JQuery methods `ajaxStart` and `ajaxComplete` in following way:

```
// our JavascriptInterface
public class AjaxHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "AjaxHandler";
    private final Context context;

    public AjaxHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void ajaxBegin() {
        Log.w(TAG, "AJAX Begin");
        Toast.makeText(context, "AJAX Begin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void ajaxDone() {
        Log.w(TAG, "AJAX Done");
        Toast.makeText(context, "AJAX Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And here is how the `AjaxHandler` is used in `Activity`:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // get web view
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web); 

        // configure web view 
        final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://foo.com");

        // add javascript interface
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new AjaxHandler(this), "ajaxHandler");

        // override onPageFinished method of WebViewClient to handle AJAX calls 
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                    view.loadUrl("javascript:$(document).ajaxStart(function (event, request, settings) { " +
                            "ajaxHandler.ajaxBegin(); " + // Event called when an AJAX call begins
                            "});");
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) { " +
                            "ajaxHandler.ajaxDone(); " + // Event called when an AJAX call ends
                            "});");

            });
    }
}
```

The main idea is taken from [here](http://www.solstice-mobile.com/blog/handling-ajax-calls-on-web-views) and presented with some tweaks.
Although its a little late to submit an answer but hope this helps others as well!

Comment: It's great solution. But how can I get the request parameters in AjaxHandler from the js code?

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Also, I just want to let know that ajaxStop could be better in this case because is triggered when the ajax actually stops loading. 
source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421115/706833

Comment: @S1LENT WARRIOR I put code as it is but any how Toast not show

Comment: can get ajax response after send form data? form webpage display in webview from remote url

Comment: This works great! However I had to decorate the local ajaxDone and ajaxBegin methods with the attribute @JavascriptInterface as described here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: This code is not clear, I copied it and not works !!, Can you please make a project on gitHub

Answer (score 0):

The year is 2023, and I faced the same problem.

I solved it using the `shouldInterceptRequest()` method. The hack is to filter through the requests that are being intercepted and act accordingly.

`shouldInterceptRequest()` method intercepts all requests that are made on your `WebView`. In my case, I know the exact requests that are being made and in that case, the exact URLs associated with the requests.

```js
@Nullable
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

  String sURLPatternExpected = "";
  if (request.getUrl().toString().contains(sURLExpected)) {

    String sExactURLExpected = "";
    if (!request.getUrl().toString().equals(sExactURLExpected)) {
      //  User is going outside your expected URL.
    } else {
      //  User is going outside your expected URL.
    }

  }

  return null;
}
```

In the above snippet, you first check whether a request URL matches a pattern you're looking for. For instance, if you're interested in URLs like `http://example.com/app/resource?message=hello`, filtering in the above way, will prevent you from actioning on URLs like `http://example.com/favicon.ico`.

Next thing would be to now check for the exact URLs you expect in the filtered group of URLs.

Finally, I return `null` to let the `WebView` handle the request normally.