# What are the differences between normal and slim package of jquery?

Tags: jquery, slim-jquery

At [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery) jquery.slim package is placed. It has a smaller size. What are the major differences from an original? A quick look at the code didn't bring the answer, and at the https://jquery.com I've not found any reference about `slim` package.

So, what are the differences between `jquery.js` and `jquery.slim.js`?

Comment: https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/

Comment: In my view, you accepted a mediocre answer and should change that.

Comment: @RobertSiemer, may be, but votes of hundred peoples shows actuality much clearly in time in my view. Accepted answer was complete enough and timely and now still giving the short, quick and use enough solution.

Comment: I totally disagree with you. Votes on accepted answers indicate nothing compared to other answers below (and you should know that). And whatever the answer did back in time is completely irrelevant for a public q/a website. People come here _now_ and need the best answer possible. Further: Bhojendra Rauniyar can totally do without those 15 rep. points.

Comment: The absolute number of downvotes is a better indicator for quality in comparison to other answers.—I just realized that the second answer is actually the most voted, so there is not much more to say.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Looking at the code I found the following differences between `jquery.js` and `jquery.slim.js`:

In the `jquery.slim.js`, the following features are removed:

1. `jQuery.fn.extend`
2. `jquery.fn.load`
3. `jquery.each` (attach a bunch of functions for handling common AJAX events)
4. `jQuery.expr.filters.animated`
5. AJAX settings (`jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr`, `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter`, `jQuery.ajaxSetup`, `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter`, `jQuery.ajaxTransport`)
6. XML parsing (`jQuery.parseXML`),
7. Animation effects (`jQuery.easing`, `jQuery.Animation`, `jQuery.speed`)

Comment: Worth noting is [Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) is targeting the jQ slim release. Animations are probably the biggest point of breakage, but most of them can be done better and faster using CSS3 anyway.

Comment: Might want to edit answer to express this differently - saying jquery.each here in a list of what's removed is confusing.

Comment: If you view the first line of the [minified js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.slim.min.js), you'll see what's left out of slim in the build: `-ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-deprecated/ajax-event-alias,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector` (note that effects include commonly used `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`).

Answer (score 363):

The short answer taken from the [announcement of jQuery 3.0 Final Release](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/) :

> Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the ajax and effects modules, we’re releasing a “slim” version that excludes these modules. All in all, it excludes ajax, effects, and currently deprecated code.

The file size (gzipped) is about 6k smaller, 23.6k vs 30k.

Answer (score 44):

At this time, the most authoritative answer appears to be in this [issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2995), which states "it is a custom build of jQuery that excludes effects, ajax, and deprecated code." Details will be announced with jQuery 3.0.

I suspect that the rationale for excluding these components of the jQuery library is in recognition of the increasingly common scenario of jQuery being used in conjunction with another JS framework like Angular or React. In these cases, the usage of jQuery is primarily for DOM traversal and manipulation, so leaving out those components that are either obsolete or are provided by the framework gains about a 20% reduction in file size.

Comment: Can also be used by developers who use modern features such as `fetch()` which is a modern replacement for `XMLHttpRequest` (AJAX).

Answer (score 36):

The jQuery blog, [jQuery 3.1.1 Released!](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/), says,

> **Slim build**
>
> Sometimes you don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many standalone libraries that focus on ajax requests. And often it is simpler to use a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all your web animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the ajax and effects modules, we’ve released a “slim” version that excludes these modules. All in all, it excludes ajax, effects, and currently deprecated code. The size of jQuery is very rarely a load performance concern these days, but the slim build is about 6k gzipped bytes smaller than the regular version – 23.6k vs 30k.

Answer (score 24):

I could see `$.ajax` is removed from jQuery slim 3.2.1

From the jQuery [docs](https://jquery.com/download/)

> You can also use the slim build, which excludes the ajax and effects modules

Below is the comment from the slim version with the features removed

```
/*! jQuery v3.2.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
```

Comment: What is the alternative to $.ajax?

Comment: @Zyo either use xmlhttprequest object in plain JavaScript or use jQuery normal version.

Comment: fetch API is native and really powerful 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
here how to use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @Octavioamu fetch is an option, but may need a polyfill based on supporting browsers

Comment: Now that IE 11 is finally disappearing in June 2022 the fetch API is a go, see https://caniuse.com/?search=fetch

Answer (score 7):

As noted the Ajax and effects modules have been excluded from jQuery slim the size difference as of 3.3.1 for the minified version unzipped is 85k vs 69k (16k saving for slim) or 30vs24 for zipped, it is important to note that [bootstrap 4 uses the slim jQuery](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) so if someone wants the  full version they need to call that instead

Answer (score 3):

There was a big difference when I wanted to use jQuery UI With the slim version of jQuery, it is impossible. In fact, **the slim version excludes the ajax and effects modules**

Answer (score 1):

I found a difference when creating a Form Contact:
**slim** (recommended by boostrap 4.5):

- After sending an email the global variables get stuck, and that makes if the user gives f5 (reload page) it is sent again.
  **min**:
- The previous error will be solved. how i suffered!

Answer (score -2):

i've just found out that a selector by an element attribute won't work with slim.

```
$('input[type="textarea"]').each(function(index) {});
```

hope this may help you.

Comment: jQuery slim certianly lets you select an element by attribute - but it probably needs to be a valid element, there is no input-type for textarea; `<input type="text" />` and `<textarea></textarea>` are very different things.