# How to import/require the slim version when the package is installed by npm?

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm, webpack, socket.io

When I import(ES6) or require(CommonJS) a package installed by npm, is it possbile to specify the slim version ?

For example I `npm install socket.io-client`, `socket.io-client` provides `socket.io.slim.js & socket.io.dev.js` according to https://socket.io/docs/v2/client-installation/  I use ES6 import `import io from 'socket.io-client'` in my code.

Is it possbile to use `socket.io.dev.js` for development and `socket.io.slim.js` for production ?

I use `webpack` to bundle the code. I can't find the options to let webpack use `socket.io.slim.js` instead of `socket.io.js`. The [build mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/) won't work because that will only use the "normal"production version `socket.io.js` not the slim version.

BTW, I am not sure if `.slim.js` is a standard name extension for javascript library, but it seems to be introduced by jQuery as a build without some extensions, as discusses here [What is slim in file.slim.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743980/what-is-slim-in-file-slim-js). For `socket.io.slim.js` is the " Production version, without debug"

Comment: Why? The size of the dependency on the server almost certainly doesn't matter, and for things like the example you're using, socket.io already gives you every version during install, so you can then forward the most suitable version for clients (not your server) as needed by you.  As for "is possible to [...]": yes. That's what your [build mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/) is for.

Comment: I don't want debug package bundled in socket.io.js. But that is another question.

Comment: I remember I tried build mode and it didn't work. I will double check

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have double checked that build mode will use the “normal” version not the slim version.  I updated my question to make it more clearer.

Comment: Again though: why? The regular version is 19kb, the slim version is 15kb, that is a meaningless difference. However, if you need it to work client-side, then have a look at telling webpack that [your library is external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) and that you're going to make sure it has a `<script>` element on the page your bundle will end up used in, so that webpack doesn't need to bundle it in. It'll leave the name alone and trust that when this code runs, that library's namespace works.

Comment: It is a long story but take a look at these 2 issues if you are really interested https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/729 & https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1328

Comment: I don't, "the regular version doesn't work in IE11 and slim does" is good enough (if that's actually true). These issues don't explain why you anyone would need slim, rather than the regular version though, but as with anything that you want to explicitly load in the browser when it comes to webpack, externals lets you do that.

Comment: Fare enough, but I was a bit curious that the size was definitely not my concern. Isn't that obvious ?

Comment: I also had updated my question to mention "For socket.io.slim.js is the " Production version, without debug"

Comment: that's a good update. Externals should work just fine then.