# TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Obviously I need to elaborate. **Every single function even ones that can be replaced by vanilla JS, are jQuery functions that work, but the AJAX function does not work.**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        email: emailInput,
        mode: 0
    },
    url: "main.php",
    cache: false
}).done(function(response) {

});
```

I tried it without promises, I tried it as $.post, I tried everything but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried debugging the code with the dev tools of your browser?

Comment: Type $ in the browser console. What does it show?

Comment: try `jQuery.ajax` instead of `$.ajax`

Comment: @Kevin function r()

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan I tried that it still gives an error

Comment: then, make sure you are including jquery library js file like (<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>) in your page

Comment: @User9123theRebel do other jquery functions work? or are they all failing?

Comment: @KevinCollins Typing $ even on about:blank in Chrome (at least) won't be a true test as the inspector provides it's own `$` which acts similar to jQuery.

Comment: do you have a fiddle for this? Sounds really weird

Comment: If you're not wrapping your AJAX call in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, then jQuery might not yet be loaded when the call is made.

Comment: @mariocatch  READ. THE. FIRST. PART. OF. MY. QUESTION.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan READ. THE. FIRST. PART. OF. MY. QUESTION.

Comment: @e_i_pi READ. THE. FIRST. PART. OF. MY. QUESTION.

Comment: @User9123theRebel read our comments... post a fiddle

Comment: @User9123theRebel Dear it seems like you haven't included jquery library , before running jquery ajax function

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan Read it again maybe my English was bad

Comment: @User9123theRebel You sure you have included `jquery` library on your page? Also you have tried `jQuery.ajax`? right

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan Read the title

Comment: @User9123theRebel are you going to post your jsfiddle or not? we can't help you if you don't tell us more. We're all asking the same question because you aren't telling us anything

Comment: @mariocatch What do you need to know? I told you every jQuery function works except $.ajax

Comment: Yes but that's obviously because of a user error since $.ajax is a well working API. We need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 6):

Quite late, but have you regular version of jQuery? *Slim* version doesn't contain ajax functions among others. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is part of the `jQuery` API. In order to use it, you need to make sure `jQuery` is included somewhere on your page, *above* the usage of it. Also, make sure you're calling it after `jQuery` has been loaded on the page.

Like this:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log($.ajax);
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Read the first part of my comment **I don't know why it says it's not a function when every single function is a jQuery function other than getElementById and my own functions. But somehow ajax doesn't work.**

Comment: See my edit. Also, post your entire HTML in a fiddle so we can help you out more.