# Bootstrap 4 + JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm working on an app where I use both Bootstrap 4 and JQueryUI (namely, the draggable & droppable features).

Thus far it's worked fine, but now when I'm trying to use Bootstrap and JQuery to display modals, like so:

```
$("#modal1").modal({});
```

I get a console error saying $(...).modal is not a function. So I figured my JQuery loading script is in the wrong place, but moving it around, such as before the Bootstrap css and scripts, results in a bunch of errors of this sort:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

and draggable is a JQueryUI function.

Does my head tag look alright or what's up? Why doesn't Bootstrap want to co-operate with me?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans|Ubuntu:700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Let me know if I need to provide any more details. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery

Comment: So bootstrap4 targets 3.1 slim, so they're in the correct order, but then you also load jquery 1.12

Comment: Taking out jquery 1.12 results in draggable not functioning anymore, though? Seems like jquery-ui needs the 1.12 load script there in order to function.

Comment: According to [this page](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.12/) *jQuery UI 1.12 supports jQuery 1.7 and newer.* so try changing jquery-3.1.1.slim to jquery-3.1.1.min.js (full) and remove the old jquery 1.12.4.   The version numbers of jquery and jquery-ui have no relation to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are loading jquery twice remove this :-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try replacing the slim version of jquery at top with jquery 3.2.1 i.e
replace slim line with 

`<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! However, is it a problem that I'm loading jquery twice regardless? Jquery-ui seems to stop working whenever I remove the older jquery load script. Now, though, when I replaced the 3.1.1. slim Jquery with 3.2.1 min, it works flawlessly.

Comment: *slim* version does not include everything that jquery-ui needs, because, well... it's a slim version