# off FUNCTION jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a validation form in a .php file , so it works in a way that once the field validation is done the form gets submitted . My form although is getting submitted but for that I need to press the submit button twice . Below is the code , the problem is mainly in the script section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .container{
      margin-top: 20px;
      width: 500px;
    }
    #content{
      resize: none;
    }
    #success{
      display: none;
    }
    #failure{
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1 class="display-3">Get in Touch</h1>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="failure">
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success">
  <strong>Well done!</strong> We will get back to you ASAP.
</div>
  <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

  </div>
</body>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var missing="";
  if($("#email").val()=="")
  {
    missing=missing+"<p>Email is Missing</p><br>"
  }
   if($("#content").val()=="")
  {
    missing=missing+"<p>Content is Missing</p><br>"
  }
   if($("#subject").val()=="")
  {
    missing=missing+"<p>Subject is Missing</p><br>"
  }
  if(missing!="")
  {
    $("#failure").html(" <strong>Oh snap!</strong><br>."+missing);
    $("#failure").show();
  }
  else{
    $("#failure").hide();
    $("form").off("submit").submit();    <- Problematic line 
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note, `missing = missing...` should be `missing += missing...` if you want to show all errors

Comment: I think `missing = missing + "something"` is equal to `missing += "something"` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
$("form").off("submit").submit()
```

Instead of this, use `preventDefault` to hold the form submit to check the validation, and when validation succeed submit the form using:

```
$("form").submit();
```

Comment: not happening mate. 
Same thing is happening , I need to click submit twice to make a submission .

Answer (score 1):

`.off` only removes events that were added using `.on`. It doesn't remove native events or anything like that.

You're already using `event.preventDefault()` to stop the native form submission, which is correct.

Therefore simply `$("form").submit();` should be sufficient to submit the form programmatically, once your validation is complete.

P.S. I assume you are validating your form on the server (PHP) side as well? JavaScript validation is nice for enhanced user experience but you cannot rely on it, as a malicious user (or bot) can easily change by manipulating the page source, or just ignore it entirely and post to your URL. If you value the integrity of your server and your data you must always validate forms on the server side as well.

Comment: Just tried it out but as a result , I am getting following errors:-
     Uncaught Range error Maximum call stack
    at r.fn.init.push (<anonymous>)
    at Function.ga [as find] (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
and 12 more errors , which are related to my jquery script version.

Comment: I see you are using jQuery slim. Make sure none of the jQuery functions you are using are excluded from the "slim" version. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery for a basic list. If you need any of this stuff, try using the full version of jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("form").off("submit").submit();` you can use `this.submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the order of the 2 functions:

```
$("form").submit().off("submit");
```

Comment: Reversing the order is just filling my call stack and throwing back an error .