# scrollTop not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I want to scroll page after click button to some id. Every plugin I've tried not work:

**Js Code Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#province-toggle-wrapper").click(function() {
    alert("Some alert"); //<--- alert triggers
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#profile-filter").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });

  /*$("#province-toggle-wrapper").click(function() {
      alert("Some alert");  //<--- alert triggers
         $('body').scrollTo('#profile-filter');
     });*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/master/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-filter" class="container-fluid">
  ABC
  <div id="province-toggle-wrapper">
    DEF
  </div>
</div>
```

form `jQuery.scrollTo()` plugin - top 2 methods from this [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element).
What do I wrong?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle. I will solve this.

Comment: you can just append to the url your id like url.com#myid and it will scroll there.

Comment: this isn't solution of this problem, and this is not animate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is the use of jQuery slim version.

The "slim" versions do not include several functions like animations and ajax.
The missing functions are [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35424465/2159528).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#profile-filter").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#container2").offset().top
    }, 4000);
    return false;
});

$("#province-toggle-wrapper").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#container1").offset().top
    }, 4000);
     return false;
});
```

```css
#container1{
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    background:#879655;
}

#container2{
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    background:#906354;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
    <a href="" id="profile-filter">Go to 2nd Container</a>
</div>

<div id="container2">
    <a href="" id="province-toggle-wrapper">Go to top</a>
</div>
```

Kindly check this snippet. I just include jquery library file, no other plugins.

Comment: Kind;y accept it as answer if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/Lh5mcLn7/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#province-toggle-wrapper").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#profile-filter").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#province-toggle-wrapper{
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-filter" class="container-fluid">
  ABC
  <div id="province-toggle-wrapper">
    DEF
  </div>
</div>
```

Remove all the library, just keep `jQuery` (jquery.min.js).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the document ready for jquery. Try to put your code between:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Your code here
    });
```

And here you have a good explanation of using scrollto:
[w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll)

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools. The information they provide is often outdate and sometimes event just plain wrong. jQuery learning centre is the authoritative resource for this.

Comment: don't help, and if i have to add document.ready(), why alert triggers?