# jQuery not linking properly to HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I loaded my HTML, I keep getting an error message stating that (function) is not a function. What's going on here? Here's how I have included my scripts and the jQuery itself.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

```js
var $title = $('#intro h1'); 
$title.hide().fadeIn();
```

Comment: Share your HTML also

Comment: The issue is because you're using jQuery slim, which has most animation methods removed. Use the full jQuery version instead. It has nothing to do with 'jQuery' not being linked correctly.

Comment: import proper jqury file .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - "fadeIn is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645772/jquery-fadein-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

That is beacuse you use "slim" version of jQuery which doesn't include many functions.

There is simply no function called `fadeIn`.

`...jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"...`

```js
var $title = $('#intro h1'); 
$title.hide().fadeIn();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="intro"><h1>Hello world</h1></div>
```

Just use full version

```js
var $title = $('#intro h1'); 
$title.hide().fadeIn();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="intro"><h1>Hello world</h1></div>
```