# $.ajax({}) is not a function in django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Such related question I have seen so many but none solved my problem. There is other reason why this is not working but I am feeling difficult to figure out the issue. Here is the code

base.html

```
<div class="sections-wrapper">
  {% block pagecontent %}
  {% endblock pagecontent %}
</div>
{% block js %}
  {% include 'includes/js.html' %}
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      function updateText(btn, newCount, verb){
      btn.text(newCount + " " + verb)
    }
    $(".like-company").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      var this_ = $(this)
      var likeUrl = this_.attr("data-href")
      var likeCount = parseInt(this_.attr("data-likes")) | 0
      var addLike = likeCount + 1
      var removeLike = likeCount - 1
      if (likeUrl){
      $.ajax({
        url: likeUrl,
        method: "GET",
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data)
          var newLikes;
          if (data.liked){
            updateText(this_, addLike, "Unlike")
          } else {
            updateText(this_, removeLike, "Like")
          }
          }, error: function(error){
              console.log(error)
              console.log("error")
            }
        })
      }
    })
    })
  </script>
{% endblock js %}
```

includes/js.html

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.slim.min.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/tether.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap4.min.js'%}"></script>
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block pagecontent %}
  <div class="container">
    {% if companies %}
      <h3 class="text-center bold categories">COMPANIES</h3>
      {% for company in companies %}
        {% if forloop.first %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
              <a href="{{ company.get_like_url }}" class="btn btn-link like-company" data-href="{{ company.get_like_url }}" data-likes="{{ company.likes.count }}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>{{ company.likes.count }} like</a>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock pagecontent %}
```

I have checked that the jquery is loaded and also the code is working up to if (likeUrl)

Comment: What's the **actual** error message? (Verbatim.)

Comment: in base `{% include 'includes/js.html' %}`  js script in `includes/nav.html` you have typo in question or in project?

Comment: sorry it is typo in the question. I will fix it

Comment: I get error message as $.ajax({}) is not a function

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$` with `jQuery` (case sensitive)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use jquery slim in description you can read

```
/*! jQuery v3.2.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
```

ajax is exclude in slim version

more [release-note](https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/20/jquery-3-2-1-now-available/)

Comment: Or link self.valuable_content: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37750393/1600649

Comment: yeah it worked now when using minified version instead of slim

Answer (score 0):

Yes, include ajax in slim version or use min library instead of jquery.slim.min.js