# Bootstrap4 DataTables example not working

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to run the example from https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html

My code looks like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#maintable').DataTable();
});
```

But I keep getting an error in the browser console... the function `DataTable` is not defined... What am I missing?

Comment: Try to change position of **jquery-1.12.4.js** to top of all **js**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run two jQuery versions and two bootstrap versions.

The jQuery 3.2.1 slim **and** the 1.12.4.

I suggest you to try this in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

And this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#maintable').DataTable();
});
```

**Note:** The jQuery link above is not the "slim" version... The slim version exclusions are [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35424465/2159528). Unless you are certain you don't need Ajax and the jQuery animation effects, I suggest you use to use  full version.

**Note from the question's poster** ***(see edits)***:
The last thing I fixed myself to make it work was to add `<THEAD>` and `<TBODY>` (it's not sufficient to have a table structure with just `<tr>` and `<td>`).

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <!-- some <th>... -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Here is a [2013 example](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/empty-table-markup/) of a «basic HTML markup structure» for a `<table>` without data.

If you take a minute to read the comments below, you may discover some additional valid markup.
;)

And here is the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Comment: Now getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined`

Comment: [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XEEwxd) here (without data). You also have to follow the [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/).