# Why $(this).animate doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I have been trying to make animations in `jQuery` with `.animate`, for all the elements that have the class `.boton1`. When its hover event occurs, its background should change to red, but it does not work with `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`.

Redial that `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` do not work inside `.animate()`, but if it works alert ("text"). I'm using `Bootstrap 4`.

> This is the index.php file

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".boton1").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      background = "red"
    }, 500);
  });
}); > And these are my styles global.css * {
    text - decoration: none;list - style: none;
  }.cabezera - general {
    display: block;width: 100 % ;height: auto;padding: 5 px;
  }.logo {
    color: white;font - weight: bold;display: inline - block;
  }.navegacion {
    display: inline - block;border: 1 px solid red;text - align: center;
  }.opcion1 {
    display: inline - block;margin: 5 px;
  }.boton1 {
    display: inline - block;padding: 5 px 15 px;border: none;background: none;background: white;color: #1B2C3F; cursor:pointer; cursor: hand }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<header class="cabezera-general" id="cabezera-general-pagina">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <h1 class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 logo">Flush</h1>
      <nav class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 navegacion">
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Inicio</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Ordenadores</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Muebleria</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Dispositivos moviles</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Monitores</li>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas pariatur ad inventore unde aliquam beatae alias iure quasi omnis neque. Voluptates sequi ducimus nesciunt recusandae cum adipisci necessitatibus fugit doloribus.</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `{background = "red"}` should be `{background : "red"}`.

Comment: doesnt work neither :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to include the `jQuery` UI library for this to work. However, there are a couple other issues you have to fix as well. As was pointed out, `{background = "red"}` should be replaced with correct object notation `{background : "red"}`. If you want the background to return to its previous color on mouseleave, you should refactor the code and use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```js
$(".boton1").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }, 500);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }, 500);;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<header class="cabezera-general" id="cabezera-general-pagina">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <h1 class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 logo">Flush</h1>
      <nav class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 navegacion">
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Inicio</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Ordenadores</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Muebleria</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Dispositivos moviles</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Monitores</li>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas pariatur ad inventore unde aliquam beatae alias iure quasi omnis neque. Voluptates sequi ducimus nesciunt recusandae cum adipisci necessitatibus fugit doloribus.</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
```

.

With that said, the effect will be much faster and will look cleaner if you simply use the `CSS` `:hover` pseudo-class.

Hope this helps!

```css
.boton1:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<header class="cabezera-general" id="cabezera-general-pagina">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <h1 class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 logo">Flush</h1>
      <nav class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 navegacion">
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Inicio</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Ordenadores</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Muebleria</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Dispositivos moviles</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Monitores</li>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas pariatur ad inventore unde aliquam beatae alias iure quasi omnis neque. Voluptates sequi ducimus nesciunt recusandae cum adipisci necessitatibus fugit doloribus.</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three reasons occurs the error in this case.

1) `{background = "red"}` should be `{background : "red"}`

2) There are serval differences between jquery.js and jquery.slim.js. One of the difference is animate. [What are the differences between normal and slim package of jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery/35424465#35424465)

3) jQuery can **NOT** animate colours.

> For example, width, height, or left can be animated but
>   background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used

[From jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".boton1").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      fontSize: "30"
    }, 500);
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.cabezera-general {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navegacion {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.opcion1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.boton1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  background: white;
  color: #1B2C3F;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap -->

<!-- Jquery    -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Cabezera Principal -->
<header class="cabezera-general" id="cabezera-general-pagina">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <h1 class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 logo">Flush</h1>
      <nav class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 navegacion">
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Inicio</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Ordenadores</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Muebleria</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Dispositivos moviles</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Monitores</li>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas pariatur ad inventore unde aliquam beatae alias iure quasi omnis neque. Voluptates sequi ducimus nesciunt recusandae cum adipisci necessitatibus fugit doloribus.</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- Cabezera Principal -->
<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But, there's no need to do that with `animate()` since there's a better choice : CSS.

```css
* {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.cabezera-general {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navegacion {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.opcion1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.boton1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  background: white;
  color: #1B2C3F;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand
}

.boton1:hover{
  transition: background 0.5s;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap -->

<!-- Jquery    -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Cabezera Principal -->
<header class="cabezera-general" id="cabezera-general-pagina">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <h1 class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 logo">Flush</h1>
      <nav class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 navegacion">
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Inicio</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Ordenadores</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Muebleria</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Dispositivos moviles</li>
        <li class="opcion1 boton1">Monitores</li>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas pariatur ad inventore unde aliquam beatae alias iure quasi omnis neque. Voluptates sequi ducimus nesciunt recusandae cum adipisci necessitatibus fugit doloribus.</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- Cabezera Principal -->
<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: i mean... the script tag is directly in the question, it's not slim version.