# jQuery load method gives error $(...).load is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im building a page using Bootstrap and still feeling my way around. Im trying to load content to a div once the page has finished loading and Im using jQuery .load method. For some reason it always comes back as : load is not a function, even when Ive copied a working example from w3schools.

My code is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".carousel-load").load('HTML/avaleht.html');
 })
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink- 
to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<title>ASMRi</title>



</head>

<div class="carousel-load"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any sort of help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including jQuery two times in your code, and the latter (`slim` version) doesn't include `load()` function in it. Since the latter also overrides the former, you get this error.

You need to remove this line from the code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

To see the difference between the two flavors, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery) is a good start.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew bootstrap needed jquery but didnt even pay attention that the one on the bottom of the body was slim. Works a treat now. Thanks!