# jQuery .click() event isn't firing on-click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#backButton-1").click(function() {
    $("#form-2").empty();
    $("#form-1").show();
});
```

I'm having an issue getting this snippet to run. `form-1` is hidden, `backButton-1` is created after the end of `form-2` and only after `form-1` has been hidden. I want `backButton-1` to empty out `form-2` and unhide `form-1` but the `.click` event isn't firing.

Here's the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var playersName = '';
    var gameName = '';
    var playersNameArray = [];

    $("#submit-1").click(function() {
    playersName = $("#input_players").val();
    gameName = $("#input_game").val();

    $("#form-1").hide();

    gameName = gameName.toLowerCase();
    gameName = gameName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + gameName.substr(1);

    function makeArray(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\s/g, '');
        var array = string.split(",");

        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i].toLowerCase();
        array[i] = array[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + array[i].substr(1);
        }

        playersNameArray = array;
    }

    makeArray(playersName);

    function makeScores(array) {
        $("#container-1").prepend("<p>Input " + gameName + " scores:</p>");

        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var scoreDiv = document.createElement("div");
        scoreDiv.className = "score";
        scoreDiv.id = "score-" + (i + 1);

        var scoreInput = document.createElement("input");
        $(scoreInput).attr('type', 'text');
        scoreInput.id = "scoreInput-" + (i + 1);

        $("#form-2").append(scoreDiv);
        $("#score-" + (i + 1)).append("<div class='scoreName'>" + array[i] + "</div>");
        $("#score-" + (i + 1)).append(scoreInput);
        }

        $("#container-1").append(
        $("<div class='submitButtonDiv' />").append(
            $('<input type="submit" name="submit-2" value="Submit" id="submit-2" />')
        ),
        $("<div class='backButtonDiv' />").append(
            $('<input type="button" name="backButton-1" value="Back" id="backButton-1" />')
        )
        );
    }

    makeScores(playersNameArray);
    });

    $("#backButton-1").click(function() {
    $("#form-2").empty();
    $("#form-1").show();
    });

    $("#submit-2").click(function() {

    });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container-1">
    <form action="/database.php" method="POST" id="form-1">
    <div class="input">
        <p>Enter player names, separated by commas:</p>
        <input type="text" name="input_players" id="input_players">
    </div>

    <div class="input">
        <p>Enter game name:</p>
        <input type="text" name="input_game" placeholder="e.g. Smallworld" id="input_game">
    </div>

    <div class="submitButtonDiv">
        <input type="submit" name="submit-1" value="Submit" id="submit-1">
    </div>
    </form>
    <form action="/database.php" method="POST" id="form-2"></form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your *HTML* code.

Comment: Can you post a simple reproductible example?

Comment: [Read how to ask a good question on STACK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `to empty out form-2` do you want to remove the form elements from the DOM with [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) or reset the inputs to its default values with [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) ?

Comment: @empiric I want to completely empty out the form of all its elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying the button is being *created*, which means that jQuery cannot add an event listener on load. Either create the listener together where you create the button, or use propagation.

```
// Create button, add to DOM
$("<div>New div</div>").appendTo("body")
  .click(function() {
    // Attach click event listener
    alert("Works!");
  });

// Or using propagation
$("body").on("click", "#test", function() {
    alert("Works too!");
});
$("<div id='test'>New div</div>").appendTo("body");
```

Note that the second approach works irrespective of where you attach the event listener to body, be it before or after creating the new item.

In your case, I suggest:

```
$("#container-1").append(
  $("<div class='submitButtonDiv' />").append(
    $('<input type="submit" name="submit-2" value="Submit" id="submit-2" />')
  ),
  $("<div class='backButtonDiv' />").append(
    $('<input type="button" name="backButton-1" value="Back" id="backButton-1" />')
  )
).on("click", "#backButton-1", function() {
  $("#form-2").empty();
  $("#form-1").show();
});
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I didn't include the ) before .on("click" etc., I'm assuming that was a typo. If I also wanted to remove backButton-1 itself and submit-2 could that be done with a $("#submit-2").remove(); and so on?

Comment: @Alex No that is not a typo. It is a chained method. In other words: `on()` is called after `append()` is finished, on `$("#container-1")`. What it says is "if `container-1` is clicked, trickle the event down to `backButton-1` and run the function for that element".

Comment: To remove elements you can indeed use `.remove()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your links at the bottom

### and add the following link in your head

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script> <!-- <<<< This ONE--> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container-1">
    <form action="/database.php" method="POST" id="form-1">
        <div class="input">
            <p>Enter player names, separated by commas:</p>
            <input type="text" name="input**strong text**_players" id="input_players">
        </div>

        <div class="input">
            <p>Enter game name:</p>
            <input type="text" name="input_game" placeholder="e.g. Smallworld" id="input_game">
        </div>

        <div class="submitButtonDiv">
            <input type="submit" name="submit-1" value="Submit" id="submit-1">
        </div>
    </form>
    <form action="/database.php" method="POST" id="form-2"></form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Why would you load the jQuery library twice?

Comment: ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1 and the other one is/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1 theyu are different and believe it or no it there is a difference sometimes

Comment: Of course they are different, they are different version numbers. *Only* use the one that you need for your project. There are also different versions per version number, namely slim and standard. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery).