# Bootstrap add functions to slim jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4 on my website and bootstrap uses the slim version of jquery. But this version of jquery doesn't include effects. I want the effects to be included so I added the slim jquery and the normal jquery, but ofcourse it didn't work. I already tried to rearrange the scripts so slim is include before/after the normal version. Can i somehow tell bootstrap to use the normal version of jquery, or add the jquery effects function to the slim version?

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the slim jQuery, and keeping only normal jQuery in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slim jQuery is just a [lightweight version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery) of jQuery. For Bootstrap it is enough, that's why they included this one in their documentation. You can replace it with the normal jQuery, Bootstrap will still work perfectly with it.

You should only include the normal jQuery in your code.

Comment: i tried this before, but it didn't work. now I try it again and it works. I guess i did something wrong. Thanks!