# How can I emulate the jQuery $ selector in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the jQuery $ selector makes getting DOM elements a lot easier. I want to be able to replicate this selector in plain javascript. How would I do this?

Note: I do not want to replace all instancew of `$('')`in my code with `document.querySelector()`, rather, I want to define `$` as a function.

Comment: To define `$` as a function: `var $ = function() { ... `.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I want to be able to use it to select DOM elements like I would use it in jQuery, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: Implement `document.querySelectorAll()` inside your `$` function I guess...

Comment: But bear in mind it is not that simple, jQuery selector does a lot of things behind-the-scenes..

Comment: Why not just use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: @KevinBoucher You are right. That is what I used.

Comment: I believe jQuery has  a module of DOM manipulation only.. can't recall if it is the jQuery core or other specific part of it.

Comment: In addition to comments above, since you would need a lot of code to add to emulate every jQuery selector funcionality, it might be better to use querySelector and querySelectorAll, to preserve small footprint. It might overload the performance in browsers

Comment: add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` to the top of your page

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Are you talking about jQuery Slim?

Comment: @Barmar possibly.. Slim is not not just for DOM manipulation as I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37750393/1267304), but it is a nice suggestion. It would be nice if jquery had a [download builder](https://jqueryui.com/download/) like jquery ui tho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). You don't need to use the `querySelectorAll` method on `document`, it can be any DOM Element. If you want to use it in a style somewhat similar to jQuery, you can write a function that wraps it, like this:

```
var $ = function (selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
};
```

That example assumes you're using ES5 or older, and rewriting it in newer versions of the language should be trivial.

Keep in mind that this will return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an `Array` you might think it does, so many methods from it won't be there.