# disable click button on submit

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I try to update this jquery script in pure js (with bootstrap 5). The goal is to not allow someone to click twice on the payment button. Sorry I am not very strong in js.
My goal is to have the same reaction that the jquery script.

I tried to follow the process on this page :
[Disabling a button in vanilla JavaScript and in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804924/disabling-a-button-in-vanilla-javascript-and-in-jquery)

Thank you

My current script

```
<form name="checkout_confirmation" action="http://............/Process" method="post" id="checkout_confirmation" role="form" onsubmit="return checkCheckBox(this)"><section class="checkout_confirmation" id="checkout_confirmation">
div class="text-end" id="process_button" class="processButton">
<button type="submit" data-button="payNow" class="btn btn-success">Confirmer la commande avec paiement</button>    </div>
  </div>
</form>



<script>
  $('form[name="checkout_confirmation"]').submit(function() {
    $('form[name="checkout_confirmation"] button[data-button="payNow"]').html('Confirm the payment').prop('disabled', true);
  });
</script>
```

Now the script update

```
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById('checkout_confirmation');

    button.addEventListener('submit', function() {
        alert('Confirm the payment');
    });

    button.disabled = false;
    button.click(); // No output
    button.prop("disabled", true);
</script>
```

Comment: ``payNow`` is not the ID of your button, but it is ``data-`` attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) can be used in JavaScript to **set** the `attribute` of the button as `disabled`.

```
Element.setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

This can be used to disabled the button.

So when someone **clicked** on the submit button, you can `disable` the button till the data is processed.

Check the below demo code:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("submit-data");

btn.addEventListener("click", submitForm);

function submitForm(){
  btn.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  btn.innerText = "Submitting..";
  let userName = document.getElementById("user-name").value;
  console.log("Name: ", userName);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
     btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
     btn.innerText = "Submit";
  }, 3000);

}
```

```html
<form type="POST">
 <label for="user-name">Full Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="user-name" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
 <br /><br /><br />
 <button id="submit-data">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

- Submit events fire on *form* elements, not *button* elements.
- `getElementById` gets an element by its **id** and neither your button nor your form has an id. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409162/how-can-i-emulate-the-jquery-selector-in-pure-javascript)).

Comment: I change paynow by checkout_confirmation but when I arrived on the page I have a pop up appear, That's I do not want. (script update)

Comment: Why are you programmatically clicking the button if you don't want to do the things clicking the button will so?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use e.preventDefault() to stop the default behaviour of the button being pressed?

More can be read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault