# Webpack 4 is tree shaking away bootstrap, how can I prevent that?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, tree-shaking

I am trying to get a legacy app that uses the Jquery modal plugin which requires bootstrap's javascript to work within an Angular 6 and Webpack 4 project that uses a custom Webpack configuration. Everything is working except that the tree shaking that takes place during bundling is removing the bootstrap imports that are in my `vendor.ts` file because no where in my app do I explicitly use the bootstrap import.

This then causes my bootstrap modals and bootstrap dropdowns to break.

**Note:** if I add something like:

```
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
console.log(bootstrap);
```

to my `main.ts` file, webpack doesn't remove bootstrap and everything works fine.

I have already tried adding multiple entries to my `package.json` sideEffects property that has been suggested in [the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) but I am thinking that this property is used to mark code that *should be* removed. Is there a way to mark imported modules as **not** to be removed from the tree shaking process?

I have also tried the ProvidePlugin like so:

```
new ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    _: "underscore",
    bootstrap: "bootstrap",
    moment: "moment",
    momenttimezone: "moment-timezone",
    // Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
    // Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
    Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
})
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and solution was following:

**instead of using "import", use "require".**

Change this

```js
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
```

to this

```
require("bootstrap");
```

Unfortunately, I have not figured out, how to make it work with the "import".

Comment: Checkout my answer below to see how to get it to work with imports.

Comment: I think this is actually webpack tree shaking this out, have the same problem with a similar scenario.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more digging into this issue, I was getting similar issues with other imports, the root problem was that I was referencing third party libraries in more then one place.

In other words, I was importing JQuery, bootstrap, and other libraries in my `main.ts`, my `vendor.ts`, and in my **ProvidePlugin**. Once the app was bundled the different references were conflicting with each other and this caused problems in my application.

I started by cleaning up all of the references and having them *all* live in once place, the ProvidePlugin. I then also added the runtimeChunk to my webpack configuration.

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: "single"
}
```

This ensures that all of the code is referencing the same libraries. Checkout the documentation [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-runtimechunk). I'm going to leave the answer as accepted for @hostar because he did solve my initial problem though.

Comment: It's interesting though, I just read a comment from one of the core members of webpack that said you shouldn't use the runtimeChunk unless you need to. [See this comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6647#issuecomment-369868055). Once I have my angularJS app completely converted to Angular we should be able to remove all these third party libraries so ideally this is a short-term fix.

Comment: Good find @justin ! Referencing same library from few places should not be a problem, webpack is clever enough to find out it is the same thing. Using optimization.splitChunks webpack will include this library just once and create needed references in modules. I think this might be bug in webpack, because using "runtimeChunk" seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4.5 of Bootstrap I think that the better solution is being explicit about the plugins that you are using as is explained [in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/webpack/):

```
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';
```

in this way you are not loading the full bootstrap js but only what you need. Afaik, there is not need to set bootstrap as a global with ProvidePlugin if you are using this, neither special tree-shaking configuration.

Also if you are **only** using jQuery for Bootstrap, there is no need to make a special config for jQuery. `bootstrap/js/dist/util.js` already does `import $ "from jquery"`, so webpack will handle the import.

If you prefer to use [jquery-slim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37750393/930271) instead of "jquery", create an alias, so `import "jquery"` will be resolved to the slim module. In fact I always configure the alias pointing to the full version or the slim version. I found that this can avoid problems like import jQuery two times by accident..

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        // or "jquery/dist/jquery.js" for the full version
        jquery: 'jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js',
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`webpack.ProvidePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) in your webpack config:

> Automatically load modules instead of having to `import` or `require`
>   them everywhere.

Example:

```
// In webpack config
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap'
  })
]
...
```

[More info about "shimming" in the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/).

Comment: I have tried this as well, and have even tried to provide specific bootstrap module as suggested in  [this article](https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2018/02/24/Tree-shaking-with-Bootstrap-4-and-webpack).