# Why did Jquery all of the sudden stop working?

Tags: jquery

I am creating my portfolio website and for some reason the slide down method is not accepting the speed parameter. The hide method works and so does that slideDown but it goes to fast any help would be appreciated. This was working before but for some reason has now stopped and I cannot figure out why

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Portfolio</title>
<link href="../css/portfolio_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header" id="header">

    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html#resume">Resume</a></li>

            <li><a href="../index.html#about">About Me</a></li>

            <li><a href="../index.html#skills">Skills</a></li>

            <li><a href="../index.html#projects">Projects</a></li>

            <li><a href="../index.html#github">GitHub</a></li>

            <li><a href="../index.html#design">Design</a></li>

            <li><a href="../index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <resume class="resume" id="resume">
    </resume>
    <about class="about" id="about">
        <skills class="skills" id="skills">
            <img src-"" alt="">
            <img src-"" alt="">
            <img src-"" alt="">
            <img src-"" alt="">
            <img src-"" alt="">
            <img src-"" alt="">
            <img src-"" alt="">
        </skills>
    </about>
    <projects class="projects" id="projects">
        <github class="github" id="github">
        </github>
    </projects>
    <design class="design" id="design">
    </design>
    <contact class="contact" id="contact">
    </contact>
    <footer class="footer" id="footer">
    </footer>
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/porftilio.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`





  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#header').hide().slideDown(3000);
     });
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the full jQuery and not jQuery-Slim?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery

Comment: anything show up in your DevTool?