# Form submission skip/ignore AJAX function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new in php and I want to submit the form to func_login.php by AJAX, instead of using action="func_login.php". So I can handle the error on the same page when user fail to login.

but the AJAX is not working, the form submission skip/ignore the AJAX and direct to func_login php page. I don't know how to check/debug the error in AJAX. What's wrong is my code?

header.php

```
<form method="post" id="sign-in-form" action="func_login.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="mailInput">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mailInput2" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="passInput">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passInput2" placeholder="Password" name="password">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="border-0 bg-yellow btn-normal col mt-3" name="submit_login">Login</button>
</form>
```

func_login.php

```
<?php 
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $myemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']); 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$myemail."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($count == 1) {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     $salt = $row["salt"];
     $db_encrypted_password = $row["password"];

     if(password_verify($mypassword.$salt,$db_encrypted_password)){
        echo "valid";
     }else{
        echo "invalid";
     }
  }
}
?>
```

js.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-GqVMZRt5Gn7tB9D9q7ONtcp4gtHIUEW/yG7h98J7IpE3kpi+srfFyyB/04OV6pG0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<script>
//...Some BootstrapValidotor Code

$('#sign-in-form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/func_login.php',
        data: {
            myemail=$("#mailInput2").val(),
            mypassword=$("#passInput2").val();
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
           header("location: welcome.php");
           alert("true");
        },
        error: function(data) {
           alert("false");
           //HANDLE ERROR HERE (POP OUT SOME ERROR DIALOG AND STAY ON SAME PAGE)
        }
     });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Do you include the js script somewhere in the `header.php` ???

Comment: `#login_form` yet your form's id is different.

Comment: And do you include the jQuery library in the `header.php` ??

Comment: if the `$('#login_form')...` wrapped in a document.ready or something similar?

Comment: I love the stealth edit.

Comment: Makes you wonder if its worth hangin around @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @RiggsFolly Right ye are matey.

Comment: Sry, I changed the id, it's still not working.

Comment: js.php will include in html body

Comment: Still not sure if the jQuery lib and the javascript is actually incuded in the script containing the form. I am betting not @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Please remember we can only try and fix what we see. If what we see does not make much sense, then there are other questions to occupy our time

Comment: I uploaded the lib script

Comment: is that js part wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or `$(function() {..});`?

Comment: Does the `$('#sign-in-form').on('submit',function(e){` sit inside a `.ready` or equivalent? If not it is probably getting run before the DOM has completed and therefore there is no element with a `id=sign-in-form` registered with the DOM therefore the `on submit` will not correctly register and therefore wont run

Comment: jQuery ***slim*** version does not include the Ajax functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between normal and slim package of jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

PHP Header won't work in jquery
try this

```
$('#sign-in-form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
var redireectUrl = 'welcome.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'func_login.php',
        data: {
            myemail=$("#mailInput2").val(),
            mypassword=$("#passInput2").val();
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
           window.location.href = redireectUrl;

           alert("true");
        },
        error: function(data) {
           alert("false");
           //HANDLE ERROR HERE (POP OUT SOME ERROR DIALOG AND STAY ON SAME PAGE)
        }
     });
});
```