# Uncaught TypeError - jQuery fadeOut is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with Jquery. I am trying to code a preloader for my website but I receive the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).fadeOut is not a function

Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).on("load", function() {
            preloaderFadeOutTime = 500;
            jQuery(".spinner-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");

            function hidePreloader() {
                var preloader = $('.spinner-wrapper');
                preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
            }
            hidePreloader();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using this Jquery: 
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js

Comment: Beware when using `jquery.slim` commonly-used animations are not there.

Comment: @xxbinxx Thank you I did not see I used slim version I change Jquery to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js but still dont understand why is slim version for...

Comment: Check answer, I hope it clarifies your doubt. Do you have any more doubt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js` use non-slim version like `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js` and try your code again

These days most of the animations are with CSS3

checkout [Difference between normal and slim package of jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery)

check below image for more clarification. I did this so you understand better

Non slim version
[image]

Slim version
[image]

Comment: Crack!  You save my life