# Bootstrap collapse button responding but not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the famous navbar button problem not working. I made sure that my script imports are in order & the HTML bit looks good. I load it up on localhost and it does not work.

HTML:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ml-auto">
             <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#mh-home">Home</a>
             </li>

      </ul>
</div>
```

IMPORTS (at the end of the body tag):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

*UPDATE:

I posted the website here under testing: not working after trying your solutions :/

http://conuplugs.com/secret.html

Comment: I think you missed bootstrap.min.css that's why it is not working!

Comment: Hi there, I wish but I imported it inside the head tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: its work perfect

Comment: Working fine for me as well!

Comment: I made a [GIF](https://gyazo.com/83f9a524eda5a4324fa975861b6e538f), not working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r6fjvgq2/

Comment: fiddle works fine, https://jsfiddle.net/08bsykhx/

Comment: first of all you need to move your navbar from the class `row`

Comment: @NishargShah can you check you email please?

Comment: Got it bro, look out my edit answer. I checked my mail and I received mail from you

Answer (score 0):

Using the Slim version of jQuery cuts out a lot of the code that enables certain stuff to work. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35424465/2358222).

> In the jquery.slim.js, the following features are removed:
>
> 1. jQuery.fn.extend
> 2. jquery.fn.load
> 3. jquery.each // Attach a bunch of functions for handling common AJAX events
> 4. jQuery.expr.filters.animated
> 5. ajax settings like jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr, jQuery.ajaxPrefilter, jQuery.ajaxSetup, jQuery.ajaxPrefilter, jQuery.ajaxTransport,jQuery.ajaxSetup
> 6. xml parsing like jQuery.parseXML,
> 7. animation effects like jQuery.easing, jQuery.Animation, jQuery.speed

All plugins use the jQuery extend functions and alot of them use the animation functions too.

Use the full jQuery script instead.

Comment: you can also use jquery slim for that, bootstrap also suggest jquery slim, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#js. **We use jQuery’s slim build, but the full version is also supported.**

Comment: @NishargShah Ah well fair enough then. But it's something to bare in mind when using Slim version, some features might not work properly, if not with Bootstrap, then with other plugins.

Comment: I know but OP have problem in bootstrap, so i commented it

Answer (score 0):

Its works fine, I removed only `ml-auto` from `ul`

for more info goto https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

## Edit

`mh-xs-mobile-nav` this class are trying to block navbar collapsing.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#mh-home">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: add this classes to debug your menu problems, `navbar-dark bg-dark` in `nav` tag

Comment: Hey, I debugged & found the source of the problem. I have 2 CSS files: `styles.css` & `responsive.css`, when I add responsive, the bug appears. Can I send you the file & we look at it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194643/discussion-between-nisharg-shah-and-mendy).