# Bootstrap carousel only works with jquery slim

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm using a carousel for a questionnaire in my website.
The problem is, one of the question uses sortable jquery function.

My carousel wont works if I include the full jquery in my head tag scripts. It works only with jquery slim, but then, the sortable items and the animation don't work. I'm sure there is a solution but I couldn't find it anywhere...
Please does someone have a solution for me?

this is the code in which my carousel wont work (the arrows won't respond):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="jScripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

this is the code in which carousel does works but I lose my sortable items and animations:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="jScripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML/CSS code too?

Comment: Of course, I updated my question with more code

Comment: there are differences in between normal vs. slim vs. min jQuery... check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery

Comment: I know that... but thats the only way my carousel works. Do u have a solution for me ?