# JQuery slim package conflict with main library. : $(...).scrollTo is not a function?

Tags: jquery

I want to scroll but it's didn't work. Please tell the right solution. 
`jQuery('body').scrollTo(500);`

Comment: Have you installed the jQuery library? How about the scrollTo library?

Comment: You probably don't have the library loaded, before calling the function.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes! I installed the jquery-slim library.

Comment: @Daan maybe but let me check.

Comment: @Daan I replaced jquery jquery-slim.min.js file to https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js, Everything is working perfectly. Thanks

Comment: **jquery slim** doesn't include certain animations.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between normal and slim package of jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery)