# ajaxStop did not triggered after ajaxStart sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preloader

I used `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` to show and hide loading  by this way:

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $.LoadingOverlay("show", {
            fade:[100,100]
        });
    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $.LoadingOverlay("hide", {
            fade: [100, 100]
        });
    });
```

this code works. but sometimes `ajaxStop` function  did not triggered, and you have to press **F5** key to reload page. because showing loading from **ajax start** did not hide.

**I can't find the problem.**

my `jQuery` version is **2.2.4**.

**Updated**

I used `ajaxComplete` Instead of `ajaxStop` but, there was the same problem.

```
  $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $.LoadingOverlay("show", {
            fade:[100,100]
        });
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        $.LoadingOverlay("hide", {
            fade: [100, 100]
        });
    });
```

Is there anything else, that would be **useful**?

Comment: im not sure if this matter but can you put it inside the ` $(document).ready(function() { /* here ... */ } )`

Comment: @JuliusLimson Unfortunately, They don't fire inside `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **ajaxComplete**

**ajaxComplete** is called whenever an ajax request finishes, either successfully or with an error.

**ajaxStop** is called when all ajax requests complete. So unlike ajaxComplete, it won't be called if there is still a request in progress.

You should use the first if the operation you want to perform should be done for **every ajax request**.

credit for @sje397 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4419387/1475257

Comment: @Gobarah Unfortunately, I had tried it. But there was the same problem.

Comment: thanks for your help. I used ajaxSuccess instead of ajaxStop and problem solved.

Comment: Welcome, will appreciate if you +1 :)