# How to intercept ajax request in android webview?

Tags: android, webview, intercept

I want to intercept url request when user clicks on url.
Following functions works fine for normal request.

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    //some code
 }
```

But Ajax request doesn't get captured in above function.
How to intercept Ajax requests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Intercept AJAX call from WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941969/android-intercept-ajax-call-from-webview)

Comment: @Niels I ahave tried solution provided in this post.But  shouldInterceptRequest  function get called for each resource which is going to load & not only for the clicked url

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: No, I didn't find

Comment: Have a look at this answer I posted, it may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75946642/3987745