# How to check user liked a specific facebook page or not in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Here's the flow I am trying to make work:

Activity opens and a Like button is shown to user
User clicks on button and Facebook's Login Screen shows up
User logins and is directed to Fan Page (via Intent or WebView... or anything else that works :)
User likes the page
User presses Android's back button and come back to Activity
Activity resumes and checks if the user indeed liked the page.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mBtnSubmit;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1234;
    private MyBrowser myBrowser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
        myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/rvcjofficial/?ref=br_rs");

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

        setContentView(mWebView);


    }
 private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "If he did, points are given to him" - you must read the platform policy before creating any app. rewarding users in any way for liking a page is not allowed, it´s called "incentivizing".

Comment: I did this few years ago. You need to set a `webviewclient` and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. You need to check the url (String#contains will work) when the page is like for example i remember the url gives a hint when a page is liked. Best of luck

Comment: @Muhammad Babar i tried your method.i did not get any hint from the url.I updated my code. please see it. and if you know how can i implement this. so please tell me. its urgent.

Comment: how can something that is not allowed according to the platform policy of facebook be urgent? ;)

Comment: @luschn Dear sir, I am not doing any things that against the facebook privacy. i jss want that when i do the click on the like button of the facebook i will get the indication that page is liked.

Comment: we know that, but what for? you removed that part where you wanted to give points to a user from your question ;)

Comment: okey if i like a page this is the url `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/pages/fan_status.php?av=100012757304746&dpr=1` and if i unlike the same page this is the url `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/pages/fan_status.php?dpr=1`. So you must first filter out the url on the base of `fan_status` name and then can check if there is the av parameter found in the url its mean user has liked the page. Please note this is a hacky way and may break in future if facebook decided to change the scheme.

Comment: @luschn  Yeah ! because i don't know that it is against the facebook privacy.and i don't want that give points to the user. i want that how can i get that page is liked. if you know the answer please share with me. it is urgent.

Comment: scraping facebook.com is definitely the wrong way to do this, and it´s not allowed either (see scraping terms of facebook). you MUST use the graph api, and the answer from febi tells you how to get the liked pages with the graph api.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar this is not working.i think facebook changed the scheme. if i likes a page and then unlike the url is same at the both end.

Comment: this would be the api call to get the info if someone likes a specific page: /me/likes/{page-id}

Comment: i used the web to produce the urls just now. Can you share the url's that you are getting using shouldOverrideUrl method?

Comment: @luschn yes ! febi told me . but i don't know how can i implement this. i knew that this is a nooby but if you know that how can i use that code so please tell me.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar This is the url  https://m.facebook.com/rvcjofficial/?ref=br_rs.

Comment: you are not getting my point. Please note the url when you press the like button in webview.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar yes ! when i am pressing the like button it gives the same url. you can try also. it gives the same.

Comment: try intercepting ajax calls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941969/android-intercept-ajax-call-from-webview

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the Graph API. Sample code below.
/* make the API call */

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}/likes",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Also check this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes

Comment: I tried it. but i really don't know how to use it. in user id i am passing the whole link of the page.is it right ?? and please can you tell me how can i use it .

Comment: just use "/me" instead of the user id: /me/likes. either way, you would need the user_likes permission and you will not get it approved in the login review for like gating or rewarding users for liking your page.

Comment: @luschn can you tell me what can i pass in the user id ? bacause i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: i just told you...and did you read that other part? that´s the important one, about the platform policy, like gating and rewarding users.