# How can I find out if a user has clicked the google share button on my web site?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, google-api, google-api-php-client

Regardless of Interactive posts or the simple share/+1 button, I've been around the internet to find an answer for this question which ***actually works*** on PC/Mac/iPhone/Android browsers (FF, IE, Chrome, Safari).

I've found "data-onshare" property for Interactive posts to set a JS callback function but it only seems to work on PC browsers.

I'd like to know a code that works on iPhone/Android browsers. It doesn't necessarily have to be the same as the one for PC.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941969/android-intercept-ajax-call-from-webview

Comment: Thank you. but I'm trying to make it function on the web browsers not on the Web view.